# Tensor Product is an abelian group? Confused.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules), it is written that $M\otimes_R N$ is an abelian group together with a balanced product $\otimes$.

I am a bit confused about the abelian group part. Just to confirm, does that mean if $x, y\in M\otimes N$, then $x+y=y+x$?

Not:

1) $xy=yx$

nor 2) $m\otimes n=n\otimes m$ for all $m\in M, n\in N$ right? (those are the two alternative possibilities that I considered.)

Comment: Yes; it means $x+y=y+x$ and not $xy=yx$ or $m\otimes n=n\otimes n$.

Comment: @Servaes thanks a lot